# Dynamic Text in Text Area Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I would like to show a dynamic text in the text area for Spotfire.
For example, after choosing the 'Books' filter. It will show the text "Books Category" in the text area.
If I choose the filter as "Toys", the text area will show the word "Toys Category".

Comment: Showing dynamic text is easy if you are showing the value of document properties, would probably require some Iron Python scripting if you want to show filtered values. You don't say what these filters are (radio button, multi-choice,...?). Please give more context.